# Alternate to multiple if-else-if condition

Tags: bash

I know this is a very novice query but I couldn't figure out where I'm doing wrong while converting the multiple if-else statements to unary in single line.

Below is the if-else snippet:

```
if [[ ${ENVT} == "right" ]]
then
isRight
else
if [[ ${ENVT} == "left" ]]
then
isLeft
else
if [[ ${ENVT} == "middle" ]]
then
isMiddle
else
if [[ ${ENVT} == "level" ]]
then
isLevel
fi
fi
fi
fi
```

Every `if` condition check is invoking it's respective function. Here is my attempt to convert this:

```
(( ${ENVT} == "right" ? isRight : ${ENVT} == "left" ? isLeft : ${ENVT} == "middle" ? isMiddle : ${ENVT} == "level" ? isLevel : exit ))
```

Any pointers where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This might help: `help case`

Comment: @Cyrus: Thanks but I don't wanna use case

Comment: Good question, also some support: don't use case (easy to write, but hard to read)

Comment: Arithmetic expressions such as within `(( ))` supports inline if-then-else, but doesn't support either string comparison or conditional execution. You could use `&&` and `||` connecting a bunch of commands, but that's really easy easy to get wrong. I'd recommend either using case, or pretty much what you have but with `elif` instead of `else if` (and removing all but one `fi` at the end).

Comment: It's possible to use [`eval`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/eval) to act as sort-of a function pointer, but it can be tricky. I don't know what you and JonathanDavidArndt have against `case` - it's only hard to read if you try to do too much in it... each case could call a function instead.

Comment: @JonathanDavidArndt Surely a case statement is dramatically much easier to read than both this nested `if` and the nested ternary variant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the one liner you were trying for, but I find this syntax nice and compact, and very easy to understand when coming back to it months later.

```
#!/bin/bash
[[ ${ENVT} == "right" ]] && isRight
[[ ${ENVT} == "left" ]] && isLeft
[[ ${ENVT} == "middle" ]] && isMiddle
[[ ${ENVT} == "level" ]] && isLevel
```

Comment: I wrote exactly the same you gave here & yeah, you read my mind about the one liner :)

Answer (score 3):

Well, if we're golfing this:

```
$(command -v "is${ENVT^}"
```

It capitalizes the variable, prepends `is`, and runs the result only if it's a valid command.